# Add gridview in word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ms-word, office-interop

I want to add gridview in the following code.
How do I add a Gridview into a word document?

My Word document creation code ;

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = null;

DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

object readOnly = true;
object inVisible = true;

aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref inVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "##formkodu##", TextBox1.Text);
this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "##sirketadi##", DropDownList11.SelectedItem.Text);
this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "##il##", ddliller.SelectedItem.Text);
this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "##isletme##", ddlisletmeler.SelectedItem.Text);
this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "##yüklenicifirma##", ddlyükleniciler.SelectedItem.Text);           


wordApp.Visible = false;
aDoc.Activate();

aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

wordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(aDoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is not a COM ActiveX control, so it cannot be hosted on Word's document surface - at least, not directly.

If you were able to use VSTO then you could use VSTO's built-in tools to wrap the Gridview in a COM ActiveX control in order to place it on the document surface. VSTO is not supported in ASP.NET, however.

A possible way around this could be do develop a VSTO Add-in that's installed on the machines where the document you create is opened. That could take care of wrapping, inserting and managing the ActiveX control + Gridview.

But you might be better off to simply generate a Word table in the document? That works fine using the Interop (or Open XML)...

There is some old information about the basics for creating an ActiveX control on MSDN, by Geoff Darst: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71a75dc4-dcea-454a-9e4a-011a2f811994/vsto-activex-and-powerpoint?forum=vsto

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4282a65c-ccd7-4fd4-a56c-75f84615fff6/embedding-active-x-control-in-office-application-using-vsto-2005?forum=vsto

Comment: How can I do this on the web form ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of interops i would prefer using OpenXML (`*.docx`) if it possible. How to create a table is documented here: [How to: Insert a table into a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/cc850841.aspx). With this you don't need interops, which can cause a lot of trouble if the wrong office version is installed or any other issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't address the question of how to add a Gridview.